# getByTestID not working for custom component

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

Working on writing a unit test for a large component. I've written one before for a smaller component, but this has several other custom components nested inside. I'm trying to select it so I can then figure out what to do with it, but I can't even get to that point right now.

## MainComponent.tsx

This is a part of what's getting rendered by the component. PriceOverrideDateRange is another custom component, and I'm trying to target it with the testID

```
       <Counter
        />
              <MainComponentRange testID='range' />
        <Counter
        />
```

## MainComponent.test.tsx

This is the part of the test I'm working on

```
  it('should be able to change the ranfe', () =>{



    //Mock out dependent function with jest
    //Nothing here right now...

    //Render with the props you want
    const { getByTestId } = render(        
          <MainComponent />
```

);

```
    //Locate screen components for test
    const range = getByTestId('range');


    //Perform user actions
    fireEvent.changeText(range, "01/22/2022");


    //Measure against expect cases
    expect(dateRange).toBe("1/22/2022");

  });
```

And this is the error message I'm getting:

```
  ● Main Component Test › should be able to change the range

    Unable to find an element with testID: dateRange

      143 |
      144 |     //Locate screen components for test
    > 145 |     const dateRange = getByTestId('range');
          |                       ^
      146 |
      147 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the testID to the component as props and then add it the the view you are using I will add a simple example.

```js
const App = () => {
  return <PriceOverrideDateRange testID="dateRange" />
}
```

```js
const PriceOverrideDateRange = ({testID}) => {
  return <View testID="dateRange" ><Text>Hello</Text></View>
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had no idea that's how the interaction worked